# The Liquibase in my JHipster project is making all my date types TINYBLOB

Tags: jhipster, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

My liquibase makes my date types to be `TINYBLOB`, for example this what all my generated changelog files look like 
`<column name="created_date" type="TINYBLOB"/>`

I would like whenever i generate changelog files with `mvn liquibase:diff` my date types to be `DATETIME` or something. Where do i configure this ?

I am using MySQL, my
JHipster version : 5.7.2

Comment: This looks more like a Liquibase issue than a JHipster issue. Have you tried running liquibase directly from command line to avoid any classpath configuration in pom.xml? (see https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) and if it fails too, you should report it to Liquibase project on github

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes, i have tried all you have mentioned. Guess i'll wait for response from them on their git-hub, i found an issue already opened for this. has been since April though

Comment: Alternatively you could run Liquibase under debugger and fix it.